# VBA code for copying and pasting a value from a specific cell that is changing as the macro runs

Tags: excel, vba

I'll try (as best I can) to explain the code I'm using

Essentially I have an excel which outputs a value to cell W151 based on a calculation that depends on cells in the range Q149:Q182.

The first step is to reset all the values in the range Q149:Q182 to their base values by copying and pasting from cells S149:S182.

Based on the base values for the formula, I copy and paste the value outputted to W151 into W99

Next, I change the value in Q149 to "2". This updates the calculation and hence the value in cell W151 which I then copy and paste into W100

Then I change Q150 to "2" and again copy the value from W151, this time into W101 and so on and so forth

My question is, is there a way of setting the cells that i'm changing as an array (picked by the user through a prompt), the output cell W151 as a variable (picked by the user through a prompt) and the destination for the copied values (i.e. currently cells W99:W101) as an array also picked by the user via a prompt. If not is there any way you can think of that might automated this process?

I appreciate that I might have done a poor job explaining what I'm trying to do so please feel free to ask for clarifications (although I warn you my VBA knowledge is very limited)

Many Thanks,

Thomas

```
Sub Example()

Range("S149:S182").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("Q149").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("W151").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("W99").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("Q149").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("W151").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("W100").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("Q150").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("W151").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("W101").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the calculation in `W151`?  And this is done until all values in `Q149:Q182` are 2 and each calculated value has been pasted into `W99:W132`?

Comment: Your code is needlessly verbose and inefficient. For example, the first 4 lines of code could be replaced simply by `Range("S149:S182").Value = Range("Q149:Q182").Value`. You might benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248)

Comment: The calculation into W151 is massively complicated so I don't think I'd be able to explain it properly but yes that's exactly it, I'm changing the values in Q149:Q182 one by one to 2 and copying and pasting the output for every step in cells W99;W132

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the tip, will change it now

Comment: Could you give us the formula you're using?  It might be massively complicated, but can read out of the formula what it's doing - someone on here might be able to speed it up or think of a better way of doing it.

Comment: The actual formula itself is just a simple average of two cells =AVERAGE(C183:D183) but C183 and D183 a linked up to an entire model that can't be explained without sending you the excel (which I can't do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite the way I was hoping to do it as this still relies on putting values on the worksheet.

<del>There's one step missing that I didn't understand:</del>

> Based on the base values for the formula, I copy and paste the value
>   outputted to W151 into W99

This is done before you turn the first value to 2.  So is it a case of the base average goes into `W99`, then you change the first value to 2 and that goes into `W100`.  i.e. If you start with 34 values in column Q you'll end with 35 values copied to column W?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set CopyRng = .Range("Q149:Q182")
        CopyRng.Value = .Range("S149:S182").Value

        .Range("W99").Value = .Range("W151").Value
        For Each rCell In CopyRng
            rCell.Value = 2
            'Q149 Offset by -49 rows and +6 columns = cell W100.
            rCell.Offset(-49, 6).Value = .Range("W151").Value
        Next rCell

    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
To ask the user to make the selections you could use the following method.
One problem that hasn't been addressed in this code is if the user presses [Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609479/handle-cancellation-of-inputbox-to-select-range), but hopefully the link will point you in the right direction - I liked the answer given by @DirkReichel.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim rCalculation As Range
    Dim rDestination As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    'Creating the base values is a manual operation now.
    'CopyRng.Value = Sheet1.Range("S149:S182").Value

    Set CopyRng = Application.InputBox("Select range to be evaluated.", Type:=8) 'Q149:Q182

    'Calculation must be a single cell.
    Do
        Set rCalculation = Application.InputBox("Select cell containing calculation.", Type:=8) 'W151
    Loop While rCalculation.Cells.Count <> 1

    'First cell in destination must be a single cell.
    Do
        Set rDestination = Application.InputBox("Select first cell to be pasted to.", Type:=8) 'W99
    Loop While rDestination.Cells.Count <> 1

    rDestination.Value = rCalculation.Value
    For Each rCell In CopyRng
        rCell.Value = 2

        rDestination.Offset(rCell.Row - CopyRng.Row + 1).Value = rCalculation.Value
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Had a re-read of your question and updated the code to reflect what I didn't understand.  First average is pasted to W99, then the updated ones to W100 onwards.

Comment: You've ticked this as accepted, but I've noticed it doesn't actually answer the question you asked:  _My question is, is there a way of setting the cells that i'm changing as an array (picked by the user through a prompt)_.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas first of all welcome!

Make the necessary changes (Sheet name or ranges) and try:

```
Sub Example()

    With (Sheet1) '<= Change Sheet Name if needed
        .Range("S149:S182").Copy .Range("Q149")
        .Range("W151").Copy .Range("W99")
        .Range("W151").Copy .Range("W100")
        .Range("W151").Copy .Range("W101")
        .Range("Q149").value="2"
        .Range("Q150").value = "2"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That would copy the formula from `W151` as well.  The OP just needs the value - I'm thinking either extend the formula down so it can be done in one hit, or pull all the values into a VBA array and perform the calculation there before putting it back on the sheet - mutliple copy/paste will be slowing the code down.  Depends on the calculation though.

Comment: Ideally the array version would be best, I just don't know how to do it

Comment: If i could define Q149:Q182 as an array and then just cycle through each value in the array changing it to 2 and output the value of W151 into another array defined as W99:W132 that would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of unnecessary things in your code simply use inputbox to get the range and use it as required.

```
Sub Example()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select range1", Type:=8)
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select range2", Type:=8)

With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("Q149:Q182").Value = rng1.Value
.Range("W99").Value = rng2.Value
.Range("Q149").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
.Range("W100").Value = rng2.Value
.Range("Q150").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
.Range("W101").Value = rng2.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Imran, I tried that but the value being pasted in to W99 to W101 is the same (i.e. i think it's being overwritten and outputting the same W151 value into all three cells)