# VBA- saving selected range (by user) of cells as pdf

Tags: excel

i am a beginner at VBA and need help with this code. I placed on my sheet command button and connected it with  macro (the code is down there) "PrintSelectionToPDF" and it goes smoothly through code until i press button cancel (if changed my mind and don't want to save selected range as PDF) in inputbox it sends me error message -> run-time error '424' Oject required [enter image description here][1] 
**-> this part of code->**
 `Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)`

Thank you in advance if you can find me a solution.

```
 `Sub PrintSelectionToPDF()

Dim ThisRng As Range
Dim strfile As String
Dim myfile As Variant
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
Else
Set ThisRng = Selection
End If
'Prompt for save location
strfile = "Selection" & "_" _
& Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") _
& ".pdf"
strfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strfile
myfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strfile, _
FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
Title:="Select Folder and File Name to Save as PDF")
If myfile <> "False" Then 'save as PDF
ThisRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
myfile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
MsgBox "No File Selected. PDF will not be saved", vbOKOnly, "No File 
Selected"
End If
End Sub`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle cancellation of InputBox to select range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609479/handle-cancellation-of-inputbox-to-select-range)

Comment: Thank you very veryy much, solved it.